# Query returning empty list when using the distinct clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have two exact queries, the only difference is the "distinct clause":

This returns a list of around 200 elements:

```
select v."ID", v."LOGIN", v."PASSWORD"
from vilians v 
left join terrain e on (v.terrain_group_id = e.terrain_group_id)   
left join auth_terrain av on (v.id = av.villian_id and av.terrain_id = e.id)  
left join messages s on (v.id = s.villian_id and s.terrain_id = av.terrain_id and av.villian_id = s.villian_id) 
where v.terrain_group_id = '8a8484436514171a0165143979b60b93'
```

This returns nothing:

```
select distinct v."ID", v."LOGIN", v."PASSWORD"
from vilians v 
left join terrain e on (v.terrain_group_id = e.terrain_group_id)   
left join auth_terrain av on (v.id = av.villian_id and av.terrain_id = e.id)  
left join messages s on (v.id = s.villian_id and s.terrain_id = av.terrain_id and av.villian_id = s.villian_id) 
where v.terrain_group_id = '8a8484436514171a0165143979b60b93'
```

All the fields in the tables are varchar2.
And here it is a sample results without the distinct:

```
ID                               LOGIN  PASSWORD                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

8a8484436514171a0165144209701ee1 jr8anvbp 8tOm1UO3uEZrx7CtW5ZEYg==                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
8a8484436514171a0165144209701ee1 jr8anvbp 8tOm1UO3uEZrx7CtW5ZEYg==                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
8a8484436514171a0165144209701ee3 9j2c5jus u6adS77yiA6D2N+NMhpnbg==                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
8a8484436514171a0165144209701ee3 9j2c5jus u6adS77yiA6D2N+NMhpnbg==                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
8a8484436514171a0165144209701ee3 9j2c5jus u6adS77yiA6D2N+NMhpnbg==                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
8a8484436514171a0165144209701ee3 9j2c5jus u6adS77yiA6D2N+NMhpnbg==                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
8a8484436514171a0165144209701ee3 9j2c5jus u6adS77yiA6D2N+NMhpnbg==                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
8a8484436514171a0165144209701ee3 9j2c5jus u6adS77yiA6D2N+NMhpnbg==                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
8a8484436514171a0165144209701ee5 5j4yp8aj OTH+ofKXUMkmIWMrswzD4w==                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
8a8484436514171a0165144209701ee5 5j4yp8aj OTH+ofKXUMkmIWMrswzD4w==
```

The Oracle version is 11g Express Edition 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit production.

Any reason for this to happen?

Comment: If you remove distinct and at the end of the statement after where clause add `GROUP BY v."ID", v."LOGIN", v."PASSWORD"` does it also return nothing?

Comment: I'm suspicious that something else is at play, there is no obvious reason that adding distinct is altering the results to return nothing. Has the query been altered when posting?

Comment: It makes no sense, can you show us some of those 200 records? Are all of those 200 elements null?

Comment: @KamilG. When using group by it returns the data but I need to know the reason why this is not working

Comment: @Andrew nothing changed

Comment: @JaimeDrq I've just added some of the records. I'm starting to thing this is some kind of bug, but it's very strange with such a simple query.

Comment: Just for simplifying, why don't you try that distinct just with `vilians` table? You are doing a left join with this table so the distinct should be the same

Comment: @MazarD the reason I asked that is because group by every column does the same thing as distinct.

Comment: what if you remove all joins and leave only select from `vilians` still distinct return nothing? If not then add another join and another and see when you got empty result

Comment: @Livius Yes, I did that and I always get the results until I add the "left join messages". But still don't understand the problem

Comment: ok, some progress then. What if you modify this join to `left join messages s on (v.id = s.villian_id)` if you got the result (and you posted all details) than it looks to me like a bug. Also look if removing `and av.villian_id = s.villian_id` change something

Comment: only with (v.id = s.villian_id) or only with (s.terrain_id = av.terrain_id and av.villian_id = s.villian_id) it returns the data :(

Comment: Yes, I would start from the main table (`vilians`) and I would add the left joins until detect what left join is generating the issue

Comment: What about if you surround your query like this `select distinct * from ([your_query_without_distinct])` and see what happen...

Comment: @JaimeDrq Is just like there isn't subquery at all. It returns data with the direct select and returns no data with the distinct.

Comment: it's quite weird, but it sounds a database bug... Just if you really need that query, I would study other ways to retrieve that information, for example joining 2 tables in a subselect and then joining that subselect with other table

Comment: or even, replace the distinct by a group by `v."ID", v."LOGIN", v."PASSWORD"`

Comment: than it is a bug, nothing from `lef join` can filter main stream if it is put in `on` clause not in the `where`.

Comment: Yes if the filter is in the `on` you filter the table before joining with it, and if you do the filter in the `where`, the filter is applied after performing the join. It's true that  sometimes the results are the same, but not necessarily

Comment: Sounds like a bug, maybe 10094732 but there are others. You can raise a service request with Oracle to investigate further, or look on MoS and see if the workarounds, er, work for you. Or change the query to avoid the `distinct`, of course.

Comment: it looks like already fixed issue - you must update your oracle instalation